# For-loop not iterating over each of the statements

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I'm a beginner and have also had my head in Ruby for a bit, so I'm probably missing something small here.

But I'm curious why *console.log(atheletes[i].win);* is being skipped over for each iteration of [i]? I've discovered that by the time the counter reaches that point, it's already to 2, so it returns undefined because it's past the end of the array.

What's weird is if I change the semicolon from the statement before it into a comma, it works. So for some reason the iterator is only working for the first statement.

```
var tim = {
    name : "Tim",
    height : 71,
    sport : "soccer",
    quote : "Timmy the Tiger!"
}

var anne = {
    name : "Anne",
    height : 66,
    sport : "zumba",
    quote : "Anne Gonna Dance All Over Ya!"
}

//function to add a "win" property and default value to each athlete object
function addWinners(atheletes){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < atheletes.length; i++)
        atheletes[i].win = (atheletes[i].name + " won " +     
        atheletes[i].sport);

        console.log(atheletes[i].win);
}

fridays_contestants=[tim,anne]
addWinners(fridays_contestants)


/*
Current output:
=>"Cannot read property 'win' of undefined"

Desired output:
=>Tim won soccer
=>Anne won zumba
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not start a code block after your `for` loop using `{ ... }`. This way, only the statement directly after the loop will be executed inside the loop. Everything after that will be executed after the loop already finished and `i` equals 2. *Edit: `i` should actually not exist anymore at the point where you call `console.log()`, since it fell out of scope -- it has been declared inside the `for` statement.*

Try it like this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < atheletes.length; i++) {
    atheletes[i].win = (atheletes[i].name + " won " +     
        atheletes[i].sport);

    console.log(atheletes[i].win);
}
```

Comment: I figured it was something JavaScript'y! Good eye and thanks @TimoSta.

Comment: The variable `i` should not exist outside of the scope of the loop, because it was initialized in the `for` statement just FYI.

Comment: Is there any way to strike out text? In case it's wrong but I would like to keep it for the answer's comments to make sense to the reader?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have braces around your for loop, so you've effectively written

```
for(var i = 0; i < atheletes.length; i++) {
    atheletes[i].win = (atheletes[i].name + " won " + atheletes[i].sport);
}
console.log(atheletes[i].win);
```

Use braces and put both statements inside.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
function addWinners(atheletes){ 
for(var i = 0; i < atheletes.length; i++)
    {
    atheletes[i].win = (atheletes[i].name + " won " +     
    atheletes[i].sport);

    console.log(atheletes[i].win);
}
}
```

You missing {} for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var tim = {
      name : "Tim",
      height : 71,
      sport : "soccer",
      quote : "Timmy the Tiger!"
  }

  var anne = {
      name : "Anne",
      height : 66,
      sport : "zumba",
      quote : "Anne Gonna Dance All Over Ya!"
  }

  //function to add a "win" property and default value to each athlete object
  function addWinners(atheletes){ 
      for(var key in tim){
        // var atheletes= (atheletes[i].name + " won " + atheletes[i].sport);
        if (tim.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            alert(key + " -> " + tim[key]);
          }
          console.log(atheletes);
  }
}
  fridays_contestants=[tim,anne]
  addWinners(fridays_contestants)
```